# Is there a way to pass the scope to a directive templateUrl: function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that I'm calling with in a loop.  Each item in the loop has a FieldTypeId attribute, and depending on the value of FieldTypeId, I want to swap out the URL of the template.  I feel that this is a better and polymorphic approach rather than doing an ng-switch statement in the html.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in attributes">
  <div attribute-input></div>
</div>
```

Of course, the `$scope` isn't available in this directive:

```
editStudentAccountModule.directive('attributeInput', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            templateUrl: function () { // 
               var attribute = $scope.attributes[$scope.$index];
               if (attribute.FieldTypeId == 1) {
                 return '../Templates/dropdown.html';
               } else if (attribute.FieldTypeId == 2) {
                 return '../Templates/radio.html';
               } // etc.
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to load the template within the link function in order to have access to the scope, before that you just have access to the template itself in either template or compile, check out the write up here: [What are the benefits of a directive template function in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941568/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-directive-template-function-in-angularjs)

This is obvious if you've ever actually used the $compile service directly.  When you call $compile on some DOM it returns the link function which you then call passing a scope along for it to execute on.  So when you see it from that perspective it's sort of obvious that you won't have the scope until the compile has been called and the link function is returned and then called with the scope... it looks something like this:

```
$compile("<div ng-repeat='thing in things'></div>")({things:['thing1','thing2']});//Normally you would pass a scope object in here but it can really be whatever
```

Here's a bit of stab in the dark at your code:

```
editStudentAccountModule.directive('attributeInput', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            scope:{info:"="},
            link: function(scope){
              var templateToUse = '../Templates/default.html';
              if (scope.info.FieldTypeId == 1) {
                templateToUse '../Templates/dropdown.html';
              } else if (scope.info.FieldTypeId == 2) {
                templateToUse '../Templates/radio.html';
              } // etc.
              scope.myTemplate = templateToUse;
            },
            template:"<div ng-include='myTemplate'></div>";
        }
    });



<div ng-repeat="item in attributes">
  <div attribute-input info="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... I haven't used the $compile function yet, so I'm having trouble following your answer.  I'm working on developing a prototype in AngularJs to determine if we should move off KnockoutJs onto AngularJs.

Comment: Take what I wrote above not as a direct answer but just some information, you will not want to use $compile directly most likely but you will probably want to use the compile: property of the directive definition object.  The two are very closely related though since using the $compile service actually looks for directives in the markup and then calls the corresponding compile: property from a directive... that compile function must return a link function that then gets called with the scope passed along.

Comment: So at any point before the link function is called (template being set, compile being called) you don't have a handle on the scope yet.  Really though your most likely far better off in this situation just using ng-switch, I don't really understand the reason not to.

Comment: Alternatively you might look at just using the link property of the directive defintion object since that is just a shortcut and you don't really need to be doing anything in compile necessarily either.

Comment: If I put the switch statement inside the link function, how do I get the returned value of the link function into the templateUrl?

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you!! The only thing that isn't clear to me is why do you have to do the very last part: template:"<div ng-include='myTemplate'></div>".  Why is that needed?

Comment: well that's actually the part that's loading the template into the view, ng-include just loads some partial and compiles any directives found in the partial, template within a directive definition is expected to return a string that is used as the template and not do much else beyond that, so the ng-include directive needs to be used to tell it to load some other file from the template cache and process it, we just have to do this so we can update a string to be used within there within the link function

Comment: Join the #angularjs IRC room if you'd like to chat further about it there's usually someone around and I'm there half the time, my handle there is wafflejock if you want to notify me directly otherwise I don't always keep it on screen

Comment: Fantastic! This was extremely helpful and I learned a thing or two along the way. #angularjs IRC chatroom on which IRC network?

Comment: freenode blah blah blah need more chars

Comment: I wonder, is there even a way to do this without even passing in the info="item" since we "technically" already know that due to the parent scope.$index? I guess that was what was originally throwing me off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54893/discussion-between-shaunhusain-and-adam-levitt).

Comment: I will have to pick it up tomorrow as it's late here this evening, but thanks for the help! Very much appreciated!