# How to address scope value from directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do something like this

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<ui ux="main"></ui>
</body></html>
```

According to ux value, my templateUrl should change in the directive
The following code I've tried does'nt work

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("ui",function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ux: "="
            },
            templateUrl: function(scope){
                let url = "templates/dock/" + scope.ux + ".html";
                return url;
            },
        };
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? My guess is I am not being able to address the scope.value and scope.ux returns "=" . If this is the case how can I address the value from html?

Comment: Hi, please could you please tell me what version of angular you are using?

Comment: version angularjs 1.4.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pass the scope to a directive templateUrl: function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987114/is-there-a-way-to-pass-the-scope-to-a-directive-templateurl-function)

Comment: What is the final URL that you are interested in? Is it: `template/dock/main.html`? Or is it something that that `$scope.main` is equal to? If the former, then my answer below should address that. If the latter, than indeed, this is a duplicate as suggested by @iH8

Comment: yup it is template/dock/main.html

Comment: @kalpa, ok, well, then it's not a scope value, just an attribute value that you want...

Comment: Hi, you can find what @NewDev explained in his comment in the following link, under section **Template-expanding directive**  [Creating Custom Directives](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/docs/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks @Ali for pointing out the valuable link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scope` is not yet available at compilation-time where a `templateUrl` function is used. The only things you have access to are the element and its attributes.

So, what you could do is:

```
templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs){
  return "templates/dock/" + tAttrs.ux + ".html";
}
```

But bear in mind that the attribute values would be as-is strings - not their interpolated values (since all of this process happens before interpolation).

So for `<ui ux="main">`, `tAttrs.ux === "main"`. And even if you had `$scope.main = "foo"` and used: `<ui ux="{{main}}">`, `tAttrs.ux === "{{main}}"` (not `"foo"`).