# Angular Directive assign template to Body but keep same scope / controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I've been doing some research for a best-practice for loading a directive template and assigning it to the document.body with only using one directive / template.

I have a textbox, used for searching, and when the textbox is focussed an popup should appear. I know, this sounds familliar but I want to customize the values shown in the popup, that's what I need the template for...

So I want to watch for changes in the search input and view the results in a template which has been added to the body, (and keep it all within one directive / provider).
What would be the best practice for achieving this behaviour? I've been searching for hours but I couldn't find a proper solution.

```
app.directive("rdSearch", [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                onSearch: "=onSearch" // callback for processing search-query
            },
            //templateUrl: window.baseUrl + "some url"
            replace: true,
            link: ["$scope", function (scope) { }],
            controller: ["$scope", function (scope) { }]
        };
    }
]);
```

**Thanks in advance!**

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to use an provider / factory to watch the checkbox for changes and update the results in the popup template?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941568/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-directive-template-function-in-angularjs

Comment: I don't want the current element to be replaced, I want the template to be appended to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I might missunderstood your question but if you want to attach your directive template to your body, you can do it with the link function:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        angular.element(document.body).append(element);

}
```

Comment: Regarding your recent edits, replacing jsperf links with that of another tester, please seek approval in meta before making massive changes like this, especially when the links still work.  This comment will be deleted when it has been read.