# ANGULAR JS dynamic data binding to template

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

Hello All Angular Friends

I am trying to find a way for dynamic data binding to the template.

Created a test page: http://jsbin.com/jiminey/edit?html,js,output.

Currently I have my HTML

```
<banner compSrc="banner1"></banner>
<banner compSrc="banner2"></banner>
```

And the Data

```
$scope.bannerData ={
  "banner1": {
    "heading": "Hero Test"
    },
  "banner2": {
    "heading": "Page Title (h1)"
  }
};
```

Template

```
template: '<div>BannerHeading - {{bannerData.banner2.heading}}</div>'
```

How can I make this template dynamic based on the compSrc attribute?

I am looking for something like below So I dont have to update the template.

```
template: '<div>BannerHeading - {{heading}}</div>'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isolated scope for directives. Take in account the name normalization.

Here is fixed [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vecakucowa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you. That worked Awesome. Any idea how I can refer the data has "-" in between?
"banner1-Data": {
    "heading": "Hero Test"
    },

Comment: `-` is not valid symbol for identifier.

Comment: Thanks. Modified the data key, removing the '-'

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive for your template, and use `function` as value for your compile property of DDO
Plz refer this question on SO: [What are the benefits of a directive template function in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941568/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-directive-template-function-in-angularjs)

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
      return {

        // Compile function acts on template DOM
        // This happens before it is bound to the scope, so that is why no scope
        // is injected
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){

          // This will change the markup before it is passed to the link function
          // and the "another-directive" directive will also be processed by Angular
          tElem.append('<div another-directive></div>');

          // Link function acts on instance, not on template and is passed the scope
          // to generate a dynamic view
          return function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){

            // When trying to add the same markup here, Angular will no longer
            // process the "another-directive" directive since the compilation is
            // already done and we're merely linking with the scope here
            iElem.append('<div another-directive></div>');
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: This is not I was looking for.  But Thanks. I got the answer.