# AngularJs create templates directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I would like create directive with more templates.
And selected template depends on some value (like template-type).
Then if I invoke my directive in html page, and change type template-type, need changed html template.
Like this:

```
<template-factory template-type={{foo}}></template-factory>
```

I think what I can created one html template that contains all my templates, and select from **ng-if** help. But I think what it is not very well.
Help me please, select best solutions for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly in a directive you can pass a function as your template which can then return a string which is used for the template.

Take a look at [What are the benefits of a directive template function in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941568/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-directive-template-function-in-angularjs) to see how this is done and the pros/cons.

From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return 'customer-'+attr.type+'.html';
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you Joey. You very help me with my task.